# Backbone.js turning off wrap by div in render

Tags: backbone.js, render

I have model Post and collection Posts. And want to make form with list of all post in `<select id="multi" multiple="multiple">`. So i have to make a PostView render inside my #multi with just this template:

```
<option value=""><%= title %></option>
```

But finally I get it wrapped with div. Is there any solution for not wrapping this template with `<div>`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you don't define an `el` (or tagName) for the view (in the class or during instantiation) the view will be placed inside a div tag. http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-el

```
var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'option'
});
```

**UPDATE**

Starting v0.9.0, Backbone has view.setElement(element) to get this done.

```
var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var template = _.template('<option value=""><%= title %></option>');
        var html = template({title: 'post'});
        this.setElement(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this approach too, but can not see a way to pass variable for "value" inside this <option> tag. Any ideas?

Comment: Inside your view you can use jquery to set the value `$(this.el).attr('value', 'something');`

Comment: or even `this.el.value = 'something'` leave jQuery for where it's needed :)

Comment: @TomTu thanks for that, I didn't know you could set it that way :)

Comment: Is there a way to apply this easily in Marionette?

Comment: setElement will lost rendered items in each loop.

Comment: The link is not valid anymore could you please change it

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to have the view wrap your HTML, you'll have to do a few things:

1. Replace `this.el` entirely
2. Call `delegateEvents` on the new `el`

```
render: function(){
  var html = "some foo";
  this.el = html;
  this.delegateEvents(this.events);
}
```

Since Backbone generates a `div` or other tag (based on your `tagName` setting for the view), you have to replace it entirely. That's easy to do. When you do that, though, you lose your declared events because Backbone uses jQuery's `delegate` under the hood to wire them up. To re-enable your declared events, call `delegateEvents` and pass in your events declarations.

The result is that your `view.el` will be the `<option>` tag that you want, and nothing more.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Derick. I will use your advice in my future projects/

Comment: you don't have to pass this.events to delegateEvents, it will default to that.

Comment: there is a function for this in the latest version of BB - [view.setElement(html)](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-setElement)

Comment: Is there a way to implement this in regions in Marionette?

Answer (score 4):

In version 0.9.0, Backbone introduced [`view.setElement(element)`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) to handle this operation.