# marionette keep class on layout element

Tags: layout, marionette

I'm trying to preserve the full markup of a template, including the class on the root node when using a marionette region. I'm also trying to avoid creating an extra wrapping div. I've solved the problem, but in a way which I don't think is satisfactory.

I am creating and rendering a layout like this:

```
MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
MyApp.addRegions({
    mainRegion: "#main"
});

AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: '
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
    '
});
var layout = new AppLayout();

MyApp.mainRegion.show(layout);

layout.show(new MenuView());
```

And the result is that my template is rendered like this:

```
<div id="main">
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-8"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice, the class="row" is missing from the root node of the template. It appears that marionette is removing the root div from my template, and then wrapping the contents in a new div.

I have managed to hack a solution to this like this

```
AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: '
        <div><!-- sacrificial div -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ',
    onRender: function () {
        // get rid of that pesky wrapping-div
        // assumes 1 child element.
        this.$el = this.$el.children();
        this.setElement(this.$el);
    }
});
```

I'm adding an extra root div (my sacrificial div) to my template which marionette removes, and then I'm telling marionette to use the first child as the layouts 'el' (as per [Turning off div wrap for Backbone.Marionette.ItemView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656068)).

This seems crazy!

Can somebody suggest a better way?

EDIT: n.b. I'd like to keep all the template logic in the template, so don't want to have to use code in my view to specify the class on the root node - if I do this, I end up with a maintenance headache.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: '
            <div class="col-md-8"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    ',
    className: "row"
});
```

Comment: That'd do it! The only thing is that I don't want to add display logic ('i.e. the classname') into my view object. I'd rather keep it in the template. I think I prefer my current solution for this reason...

Comment: (so I'm still on the lookout for a proper solution...)

Answer (score 0):

AppLayout is missing its region(s).

```
AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: '
        <div class="row">
            <div id="region1" class="col-md-8"></div>
            <div id="region2" class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
    ',
    regions: {
        region1: '#region1',
        region2: '#region2'
    }
```

});

Then at your instantiated `layout`:

```
layout.region1.show(new MenuView()); 
layout.region2.show(new MenuView());
```

Comment: I don't think this will address the problem though will it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning the template to a string, compile the HTML into a template function with underscore. Something like this:

```
template: _.template(
  '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-md-8"></div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-4"></div>' +
  '</div>'
)
```

Comment: I don't think this makes any difference does it?

Comment: Yes, it will preserve the `<div class="row">` element. See http://jsfiddle.net/craigjennings11/gLykP/ for an example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Am I missing something though, the jsfiddle doesn't appear to have a class of row surrounding the two column divs, and the background is not gray...

Comment: Did you uncomment the `//_.template` statement and run it again?