# How to unwrap the extra HTML element generaed by View while maintaining events?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

The extra wrapping element generated by Backbone/Marionette views causes problems (with jQuery Mobile), so I need to [unwrap it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656068/turning-off-div-wrap-for-backbone-marionette-itemview).  After unwrapping, the layout is good, but events are no longer fired (see demo).

How to unwrap the extra element while maintaining events?

> ### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/dubocufifi/4/edit?js,output)
>
> It uses the [Marionette.BossView](http://justspamjustin.github.io/BossView/) plugin but the idea is the same without.

Answer (score 0):

`Marionette.ItemView` extends from [`Backbone.View`](http://backbonejs.org/#View) which has property named [`tagName`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend). When you mentioning it in view declaration your wrapping element became the element mentioned in [`tagName`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend).

For you demo example better to use [`tagName`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend) instead of changing the way Marionette renders the view.

Change you view to the following and it will work!

```
var SubView1 = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  className: 'SubView1',
  template: function () {
    return '(SubView1) Click Me!'; // moved button tag and mentioned it in tagName
  },
  tagName: 'button',
  triggers: {
    'click': 'click:button' // no need to 'button' selector, it's already a root element
  }        
});

var SubView2 = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  className: 'SubView2',
  template: function () {
    return '(SubView2) Click Me!'; // moved button tag and mentioned it in tagName
  },
  tagName: 'button',
  triggers: {
    'click': 'click:button' // no need to 'button' selector, it's already a root element 
  }
});

var TopView = Backbone.Marionette.BossView.extend({
  className: 'TopView',
  subViews: {
    buttonView1: SubView1,
    buttonView2: SubView2
  },
  subViewEvents: {
    'buttonView1 click:button': 'onSubViewClickButton',
    'buttonView2 click:button': 'onSubViewClickButton' // there was a typo here
  },
  onSubViewClickButton: function () {
    $('body').append('<div>You clicked it, and TopView responded!</div>');
  }
});



var topView = new TopView();
topView.render().$el.appendTo($('body'));
```

Hope this helps!