# Marionette-Backbone how do I make a grid table with a dynamic row and column headers

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to make a table grid with dynamic number of rows and column with headers using marionette.

I want a grid that looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/zaphod013/c3w61gf6/

So there are

columns = ['breakfast', 'lunch', 'dinner']

rows = ['carbs', 'proteins', 'fats']

and rest of the grid is checkboxes.

I have made the Views for column and row, but I am fairly lost at how to put them in the table, and then how to add the checkbox views.

Code I have is at http://jsfiddle.net/zaphod013/qkctrLxn/

`html:`

```
<div id="main-region"></div>

<script id="food-table" type="text/template">
    <thead id="column-id">
    </thead>
    <tbody id="row-id">
    </tbody>
</script>

<script id="food-col-item" type="text/template">
    <th><%= col %></th>
</script>

<script id="food-row-item" type="text/template">
    <td><%= row %></td>
</script>
```

`script:`

```
FoodManager = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

FoodManager.addRegions({
    mainRegion: "#main-region",
});

FoodManager.FoodLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: "#food-table",

    regions: {
       colRegion:"#column-id",
       rowRegion:"#row-id"
    }
});

FoodManager.Col = Backbone.Model.extend({});

FoodManager.ColCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                                    model: FoodManager.Col
                                });

FoodManager.Row = Backbone.Model.extend({});

FoodManager.RowCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                                    model: FoodManager.Row
                                });

FoodManager.ColItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#food-col-item",
    tagName: "th",
});

FoodManager.ColView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#food-table",
    tagName: "thead",
    itemView: FoodManager.ColItemView
});

FoodManager.RowItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#food-row-item",
    tagName: "th",
});

FoodManager.RowView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#food-table",
    tagName: "table",
    itemView: FoodManager.RowItemView
});

FoodManager.on("initialize:after", function(){
    var columns = new FoodManager.ColCollection([
                    {col: 'Breakfast'},
                    {col: 'Lunch'},
                    {col: 'Dinner'}
            ]);
    var rows = new FoodManager.RowCollection([
                    {row: 'Carbs'},
                    {row: 'Protein'},
                    {row: 'Fats'}
            ]);
    var colListView = new FoodManager.ColView({
                            collection: columns
                        });
    var rowListView = new FoodManager.RowView({
                            collection: rows
                        });
    var foodLayout = new FoodManager.FoodLayout();    
    foodLayout.render();
    FoodManager.colRegion.show(colListView);
    FoodManager.rowRegion.show(rowListView);

    FoodManager.mainRegion.show(foodLayout);

});

 FoodManager.start();
```

I will really appreciate some pointers on how to go about this.

Thanks for reading through.

Comment: What do you mean by "a dynamic number of rows and columns"? What you've described doesn't seem dynamic to me. Dynamic means that there could be a different number each time the table is rendered, depending on the data you load.  The table you want, as I understand it, always has three columns and three rows.

Comment: The html example shows 3 rows 3 columns as an rendered example. But if you see the js code, the row and column are collections, and are thus dynamic.

Comment: As a suggestion, build on top of another framework that already has a solid foundation. I've had good experiences doing similar things with BackgridJS: http://backgridjs.com. Columns are described as model attribute; rows are just models. The rendering of cells is wonderfully flexible. Backgrid's core components are extensible, or even replaceable.

Comment: Sounds like what you're looking for is a CompositeView that takes multiple collections. Unfortunately that's not available in the Marionette library at this time. Your HTML will not validate, but you can do what you're proposing with a LayoutView. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: @Seebiscuit, I do need some help with the Layout. I am not able to get it beyond this stage. I think I am missing some critical concept here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to this answer. First, I recommed you use a `LayoutView` with `CollectionViews`, since you don't need a template for the collection itself (you'll still use the `ItemView` templates, though). Second, you'll have to let your `Row` view know how many check-mark columns you'll need (this will be trivial as you'll see) and we'll have to create those columns in the `Row` view.

### Load up your `LayoutView`

Your `FoodLayout` view and template are perfect. You laid the foundation. What you need to populate it with is two `CollectionView` views:

```
FoodManager.ColItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#food-col-item",
    tagName: "th",
});

FoodManager.ColView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: FoodManager.ColItemView
});

FoodManager.RowItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#food-row-item",
    tagName: "tr",
});

FoodManager.RowView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: FoodManager.RowItemView
});
```

Note that I changed your `CompositeView` to `CollectionView`, and changed your the `tagName` in the `ItemView` to `tr` for the `Row` view. (**Note**: you're going to want to remove the `<th>` tags in `#food-col-item`, Backbone will generate them for you.)

### Generating dynamic columns in `Row` view

Now here comes the fun part. We're going to use `templateHelpers` to make the check-mark rows in your `Row` views. If you'll look at the [docs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.3.2/marionette.view.html#viewtemplatehelpers), `templateHelpers` is a hash that let's you add data to your template before rendering. That "data", or JavaScript objects, can be functions (since function are first class objects in JavaScript). So, we're going to use `templateHelpers` to pass the food columns we'll need check-marks for, and to put together a function that will take as a parameter the food columns, and will return with the html for those check-mark columns.

Put this `templateHelpers` property in your '`FoodManager.FoodLayout` view:

```
templateHelpers: function () {
  return {
    foods: function () {
      return this.foodColumns
    },

    addColumns: function (foodcols) {
      var html = '';
       for (food in foodcols)
         html += "<td><input type="checkbox" class=" + 
                    food + "-check"></td>";

       return html;
    }
  }
}
```

And your `Row` template will look like:

```
<script id="food-row-item" type="text/template">
    <td><%= row %></td><% addColumns(foods) %>
</script>
```

What you need to be aware of is that you need to give the `FoodManager.FoodLayout` the food columns you used for `ColCollection`, so that you can populate `this.templateHelpers.foods`. There are mutliple ways to get that in there. I just used `this.foodColumns` as dummy placeholder.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I could get it working. The only change I made was to pass foodColumns in rowCollectionView instead of the Layout.

Comment: This is the working version, for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/zaphod013/mg3xcx5h

Comment: Couple of things: 1. (minor) `serializeData` does what the `templateHelpers` attempts to do with one major difference, `this` inside `serializeData` is the view, while `this` inside templateHelpers` is the `data` mixed in with `serializeData`. If you'll look at the fiddle I removed the `food` property in `templateHelpers` and left your overriden `serializedData`. 3. (minor) I added a `tr` to your `ColView`. That replaces the bounding `div` of the view and let's Bootstrap do it's work.

Comment: 3. (major) Unfortunately, there's no *easy* workaround for the bounding `div` in `RowView`. You could attach the rows directly to the Region. I came up with a workaround for that, but I haven't tested it extensively. Here's a link to an Answer that implements it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27473851/2112866. And here's a link to an updated fiddle that incorporates the first 2 items: http://jsfiddle.net/mg3xcx5h/2/

Comment: I applied 3. Please study it carefully, there are major changes, not least of which is that it uses the current Mn ver (2.4.0). This changes `itemView` to `childView`, and `Layout` to `LayoutView`. See the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Seabiscuit/azmww8dg/1/

Comment: Thank you. I was going to try out the solution suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656068/turning-off-div-wrap-for-backbone-marionette-itemview. But I suppose this will not work since we have two regions and two divs within the layout?