# How to bind Backbone.View.el to a template without a wrapper?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Here's a template I'm using

```
<script type="text/template" id="template-message">
  <p class="message"><%= message %></p>
</script>
```

Here's my Backbone.View

```
var MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({

  template: _.template(Backbone.$("#template-message").html()),

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    return this;
  },
});
```

How I'm using it

```
var msg  = new Message({message: "hello"}),
    view = new MessageView({model: msg});

$("body").append(view.render().el);
```

Output

```
<body>
  <div>
    <p class="message">
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

I **understand why** it's happening (the default tagName for a view is `div`), but I don't want the wrapper `div` on there. I would like to see this as the output

```
<body>
  <p class="message">
    hello
  </p>
</body>
```

---

I'm aware that I could have this in my view

```
var MessageView = Backbone.View.exntend({
  tagName: "p",
  className: "message",
  // ...
});
```

The end user will be define the templates, so I don't want those things to be specified in the Backbone.View source code.

**How can I get the desired output and still bind the view to the html?**

Comment: Force your end user extend your BaseMessageView.

Comment: The end user will only be defining HTML templates. They're not creating JS source files.

Comment: Apparently you can use `setElement`. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894253/backbone-js-turning-off-wrap-by-div-in-render

Comment: @Gohn67, thanks for the pointer. I submitted an answer to this question with your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Gohn67's comment, I was able to get this working

```
var MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({

  template: _.template(Backbone.$("#template-message").html()),

  initialize: function() {
    this.setElement(this.template(this.model.attributes));
  }

});
```

If we take a look at the [Backbone Source Code](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-137), we can see it `setElement` does everything we want it to do

```
// backbone source code
setElement: function(element, delegate) {
  if (this.$el) this.undelegateEvents();
  this.$el = element instanceof Backbone.$ ? element : Backbone.$(element);
  this.el = this.$el[0];
  if (delegate !== false) this.delegateEvents();
  return this;
},
```

It even handles the event delegation. Cool!

---

I recently had to implement this on jQuery 1.3.2. **Gross**, I know, but it was a simple fix.

The only part that changes is the `setElement` bit

```
  initialize: function() {
    this.setElement(
      $( this.template(this.model.attributes) )
    );
  }
```

The `template` result must be wrapped in `$()` in order to work. I know, it doesn't make a lot of sense considering Backbone is already trying to do this automatically. It's the only thing I could do to make it work with jQuery 1.3.2 though.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Backbone.Declarative.Views](https://github.com/hashchange/backbone.declarative.views) (which I have written) and define the `el` properties – like `tagName`, `className` etc – as data attributes in the template. See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33232975/508355).